# Two string list into dictionary: key order changing

Tags: python, dictionary

I found a way to convert two lists into one dictionary in Python. So I am trying to create a dictionary from two lists. Below are the code snippets:

```
>>> v
['2', '3', '4', '1']

>>> idv = sorted(v)
>>> idv
['1', '2', '3', '4']

>>> tabv = {key:value for key, value in zip(idv, v)}
>>> tabv
{'1': '2', '3': '4', '2': '3', '4': '1'}
>>> for key,values in tabv.items():
    print key,values


1 2
3 4
2 3
4 1
```

What I am not understanding is, why is the order of key (List idv) being changed?
What I expected when I `print key,values` was:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 1
```

Why is this happening? Am I doing any mistake?

Comment: Python `dict` is unordered; the mapping between `v` and `idv` should be what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) here:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> v = ['2', '3', '4', '1']
>>> idv = sorted(v)
>>> tabv = OrderedDict(zip(idv, v))
>>> for key, values in tabv.items():
...     print key, values
...
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 1
>>>
```

Regular dictionary objects are naturally unordered; they do not preserve the order in which you insert new items.  So, doing:

```
tabv = {key: value for key, value in zip(idv,v)}
```

will create a dictionary from the two lists like you want, but the order of the items will be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` type is an unordered mapping.

If you need an ordered mapping use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

tabv = OrderedDict(zip(idv, v))
```

Comment: Theoretically correct answer, but `key:value` should be `(key, value)`, and the whole thing should actually be `OrderedDict(zip(…))`.

Comment: I had copied the code from the original question to modify it. It's now been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you need to work with ordered dictionaries:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
tabv = OrderedDict(zip(idv, v))
```

Regular `dict` is unordered.